# How to Remap Three Finger Swipe to Browser Back on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, touchpad, gestures

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop with Windows 10 on it. The problem is that I am not able to configure my Elantech touchpad to have the following gestures:

- Three Finger Swipe Left -> Browser Back
- Three Finger Swipe Right -> Browser Forward

I have [configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1T4U.png) the gestures in Registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad), however it did not have any effect. For some reason, Three Finger Swipe is still configured for switching tasks (like Alt+Tab does). Nevertheless, I was able to change other gestures like two finger tap and three finger tap. More than that, I was able to set such gestures for Four Finger Swipes. However, it is very inconvenient to browse using four fingers.

I think the problem is with Windows 10 itself as I have seen some posts regarded to that issue. It seems that OS overrides driver settings. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 limits sharply what is possible for three-finger swipe, although this might
change in the future.
For the moment, you will need a third-party product for these gestures.

One product that I know of (but haven't used) is TouchMe Gesture Studio,
available for free from the
[Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/touchme-gesture-studio/9wzdncrdg0l8#activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

This product is free to use for 32 days, after that you may either purchase
a full license for the engine or continue to use it for free for up to 3 gestures.
This works for you, because you only need two gestures.

This product is said to enable a vast array of gestures, including
2/3/4/5 Finger Swipe up/down/left/right.

Let us know if it works for you.

A review of the product with a demonstration video is available at the article
[Improving Touch Support for the Surface](https://www.poppastring.com/blog/improving-touch-support-for-the-surface).

Comment: Unfortunately, it says 'in use' for the gestures that I want to reconfigure. So, I am not able to change them. But thank you anyway

Comment: Try to undo your settings for this gesture, and set in Windows the three-finger swipes to Nothing in Settings > Devices > Mouse & touchpad (see [link](https://www.windowscentral.com/mastering-three-finger-gestures-windows-10)).

Comment: I think that these settings are only available for touchpads with Windows Precision drivers. Mine is Elantech's, so I don't have such options

Comment: The developer of TouchMe is said to be reachable at `TouchMeTechnologies@outlook.com`. You might ask him for advice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing function has effect when `ThreeFingerMove_Win10style_Enable` value is set to 0 only.

The reg file of all required values is the following:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPad]

"ThreeFingerMove_Enable"=dword:00000001
"ThreeFingerMove_Win10style_Enable"=dword:00000000
"ThreeFingerMoveLeft_Enable"=dword:00000001
"ThreeFingerMoveLeft_Func"=dword:00000003
"ThreeFingerMoveLeft_Mode"=dword:00000000
"ThreeFingerMoveRight_Enable"=dword:00000001
"ThreeFingerMoveRight_Func"=dword:00000004
"ThreeFingerMoveRight_Mode"=dword:00000000
"ThreeFingerMove_LR_ShowItem"=dword:00000001
```

The function codes can be found in `ETD.inf`, the corresponding fragment is the following:

```
; SmartPad Function Type
CLICK_SELECT        = 0
CONTEXT_MENU        = 1
MIDDLEBUTTON        = 2
INTERNET_BACK       = 3
INTERNET_FORWORD    = 4
```