# How can I configure elan touchpad 2 finger gesture right\left to back\forward in the browser?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, gestures, elan

I have Lenovo y700 with Elan touchpad. How can I change the 2 finger swipe gesture right\left so it will do back\forward in the browser (chrome)?

Comment: Do you have some screenshots of the Elan interface and the registry?  [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1430646/how-to-remap-three-finger-swipe-to-browser-back-on-windows-10) & [2](https://i.imgur.com/MqMWucH.jpg) & [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/43y14t/here_is_how_you_enable_two_finger_tap_for_your/)

Answer (score 0):

To fully control all touch gestures requires a third-party software.

[MultiSwipe](https://www.multiswipe.com/) ($5 with trial)
seems to be able to fully customize just every possible gesture.

[image]